# How to display website links stored in MySQL database table on website but show as hyperlinks to click?

Tags: php, mysql

This is a demo of a code Im working on, I have links in MySQL table and want to display them on a website table, but instead of showing the links I want to display a name same as Hyperlinks from Excel.

example: If I would just use a href=www.google.com [Link](https://www.google.com)

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pagina teste</title>
<div align="center">
<font size="+3">Lista de Websites</font>
</div>
</head>
<body>
<style>
  table, td, th {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }
  tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #dcdddd;}
</style>
<table>
<tr>
<th><font size="+2">Website Name</font></th>
<th><font size="+2">Link</font></th>
</tr>
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
if(isset($_GET['order'])){
    $order = $_GET['order'];
}else{
    $order = 'websitename';
}

if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
    $sort = $_GET['sort'];
}else{
    $sort = 'ASC';
}
$sql = "SELECT websitename, link FROM websites ORDER BY $order $sort";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr>
<td>" . $row["websitename"]. "</td>
<td>" . $row["link"]. "</td>
</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else { echo "0 results"; }
$conn->close();
?>
</table>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bull in the China shop method, surround the output with the tag markup:

```
echo "<tr>
<td>" . $row["websitename"]. "</td>
<td><a href=\"" . $row["link"]. "\">" . $row['websitename'] . "</a></td>
</tr>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate your help and every comment in this topic.

Comment: Glad to help you out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use anchor link inside table.

```
<?php
       echo "<tr>
       <td>" . $row["websitename"]. "</td>
       <td><a href=".$row["link"]." target='_blank'>" . $row["link"]. "</a></td>
       </tr>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Pagina teste</title>
    <div align="center">
    <font size="+3">Lista de Websites</font>
    </div>
    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
      table, td, th {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }
      tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #dcdddd;}
    </style>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th><font size="+2">Website Name</font></th>
    <th><font size="+2">Link</font></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    if(isset($_GET['order'])){
        $order = $_GET['order'];
    }else{
        $order = 'websitename';
    }

    if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
        $sort = $_GET['sort'];
    }else{
        $sort = 'ASC';
    }
    $sql = "SELECT websitename, link FROM websites ORDER BY $order $sort";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>
         <td>".$row["websitename"]."</td>
         <td><a href=".$row["link"]." target='_blank'>" . $row["link"]. "</a></td>
    </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    } else { echo "0 results"; }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
    </table>
    </body>


    </html>
```